# ionic install crypto-js error

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I am trying to install library crypto-js to my ionic app. Apparently, It needed the respective typings required, therefore I executed the following commands:-

```
npm install crypto-js --save

npm install typings

typings install dt~crypto-js --save
```

I have done the respective imports to the page, but it gives the following error:-

```
Runtime Error
Error in ./Page1 class Page1 - caused by: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_crypto_js___default.a is not a constructor
```

What have I missed? What should I correct in my command list?

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/third-party-libs/